# NDK_ROOT enviroment variable defined but script does not see it

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, environment-variables

In my ~/.bashrc i have this:

```
export ANDROID_SDK=~/Devel/android_dev_x64/sdk
export ANDROID_NDK=~/Devel/android-ndk-r9d
export NDK_ROOT=$ANDROID_NDK
export COCOS2DX_ROOT=~/Devel/cocos2d-x-2.2.2/cocos2dx
export PATH=${PATH}:${ANDROID_SDK}/tools:${ANDROID_SDK}/platform-tools:${ANDROID_NDK}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}
```

When I type $NDK_ROOT in my terminal I can see taht it is defined however when I'm running the script below it gives me:

```
NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment or in local.properties
```

here is the script:

```
#NDK_ROOT="/opt/android/android-ndk"
APPNAME="CrystalCraze"

# options

buildexternalsfromsource=
PARALLEL_BUILD_FLAG=

usage(){
cat << EOF
usage: $0 [options]

Build C/C++ code for $APPNAME using Android NDK

OPTIONS:
-s  Build externals from source
-p  Run make with -j8 option to take advantage of multiple processors
-h  this help
EOF
}

while getopts "sph" OPTION; do
case "$OPTION" in
s)
buildexternalsfromsource=1
;;
p)
PARALLEL_BUILD_FLAG=\-j8
;;
h)
usage
exit 0
;;
esac
done

# exit this script if any commmand fails
set -e

# read local.properties

_LOCALPROPERTIES_FILE=$(dirname "$0")"/local.properties"
if [ -f "$_LOCALPROPERTIES_FILE" ]
then
    [ -r "$_LOCALPROPERTIES_FILE" ] || die "Fatal Error: $_LOCALPROPERTIES_FILE exists but is unreadable"

    # strip out entries with a "." because Bash cannot process variables with a "."
    _PROPERTIES=`sed '/\./d' "$_LOCALPROPERTIES_FILE"`
    for line in "$_PROPERTIES"; do
        declare "$line";
    done
fi

# paths

if [ -z "${NDK_ROOT+aaa}" ];then
echo "NDK_ROOT not defined. Please define NDK_ROOT in your environment or in local.properties"
exit 1
fi

DIR="$( cd "$( dirname "${BASH_SOURCE[0]}" )" && pwd )"
# ... use paths relative to current directory
COCOS2DX_ROOT="$DIR/../../../.."
APP_ROOT="$DIR/.."
APP_ANDROID_ROOT="$DIR"
RESROUCE_ROOT="$APP_ROOT/../Shared/games/CrystalCraze/Published-Android"
BINDINGS_JS_ROOT="$APP_ROOT/../../../scripting/javascript/bindings/js"

echo
echo "Paths"
echo "    NDK_ROOT = $NDK_ROOT"
echo "    COCOS2DX_ROOT = $COCOS2DX_ROOT"
echo "    APP_ROOT = $APP_ROOT"
echo "    APP_ANDROID_ROOT = $APP_ANDROID_ROOT"
echo

# Debug
set -x

# make sure assets is exist
if [ -d "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets ]; then
    rm -rf "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets
fi

mkdir "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets

# copy "Resources" into "assets"
cp -rf "$RESROUCE_ROOT"/* "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets

# copy bindings/*.js into assets' root
cp -f "$BINDINGS_JS_ROOT"/*.js "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT"/assets


echo "Using prebuilt externals"
echo

set -x

"$NDK_ROOT"/ndk-build $PARALLEL_BUILD_FLAG -C "$APP_ANDROID_ROOT" $* \
    "NDK_MODULE_PATH=${COCOS2DX_ROOT}:${COCOS2DX_ROOT}/cocos2dx/platform/third_party/android/prebuilt" \
    NDK_LOG=0 V=0
```

Comment: You have no shebang line there, how do you run the script? What exact command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you run the script from the Bash shell? If not, you may want to define the variables in `~/.profile` instead of `~/.bashrc`.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EnvironmentVariables#Persistent_environment_variables